# How to achieve 10K concurrent connection to AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, apachebench, c10k

I have my local Ubuntu, AWS EC2 (8 Core) Ubuntu and Nginx (8 Worker) running on both the machines

When I try 10K concurrent connection with local Nginx it works

```
ab -c 10000 -n 10000 http://localhost/
```

But when I try the same with Nginx on EC2 I get the following error

```
ab -c 10000 -n 10000 http://<ec2-ip-address>/
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1843412 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking 65.0.95.45 (be patient)
apr_socket_recv: Connection refused (111)
Total of 1 requests completed
```

At same time curl command and 4K connections with Nginx on EC2 works fine

```
ab -c 4000 -n 4000 http://<ec2-ip-address>/
curl <ec2-ip-address>
```

How can I get 10K concurrent connection work with EC2 ?

Comment: Check your security group. The service is being blocked, or is not running.

Comment: From which computer are you running the command -- your own computer, or another Amazon EC2 instance? If you try to curl/wget that IP address, does it return a web page?

Comment: @RodrigoM I have updated the question appropriately

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have updated the question appropriately

Comment: Check the ulimits and worker connections for nginx and increase them accordingly